# Validate date in custom format with jQuery.validity

Tags: jquery, date-format, validity.js

Im using [jQuery.validity](http://validity.thatscaptaintoyou.com/) plugin to validate PHP form.

I need to validate whether the input date format is in **dd-MMM-yyyy**, but the plugin default is **mm/dd/yyyy**.

When I use this code,

```
$("#txtFromDate")                           
            .require()                       
            .match("date")                   
            .lessThanOrEqualTo(new Date());
```

it asks to enter date in its default format.

How to change the input date format to **dd-MMM-yyyy** (eg: 01-FEB-2012)?

Comment: Seems more of a jQuery question with the plugin since you seem to want to check it client side - if you want to check it server side (ie. after hitting submit) then use PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this code to change the date format of input string for jQuery.validity plugin

```
$.extend($.validity.patterns, {
    date:/^\d\d-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)(-\d{4})?$/
});
```

**NOTE:** 
I had to remove the checking of the input date with current date `.lessThanOrEqualTo(new Date());` as it always returned false. It seems above code does not change the format for the current date checking...